# How to get the list of path to directories which do not other directories?

Tags: go

example:

```
v2/doc/a/text1.txt
v2/doc/a/text2.txt
v2/doc/a/text3.txt
v2/doc/b/text1.txt
v2/doc/b/text1.txt
v2/doc/b/some_dir
v2/docs/a/text1.txt
v2/docs/a/text2.txt
```

This output should be:

```
v2/doc/a (because a does not contain any other dir)
v2/doc/b/some_dir (because some_dir also does not contain any other dir)
v2/docs/a
```

I know in python this could be done by something as simple as this:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False):
    if not dirs
```

I was trying to use `walk` function. `func Walk(root string, walkFn WalkFunc) error`

```
err = filepath.Walk(".", func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if info.IsDir()  {
            // here I want to check if the current dir has any other dir or not(how do I check for this using Walk or some other function??)
            // if directory is present; do nothing 
            // else store the path to a string array
        }

        return nil
    })
```

After hmm help, I wrote this.

```
var paths []string
    err := filepath.Walk(path, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if info.IsDir() {
            files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(path)
            if err != nil{
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            for _, file := range files{
                if file.IsDir(){
                    return nil
                }
            }
            fmt.Printf("%s added to PATHS\n", path)
            paths = append(paths, path)
        }
        return nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        //fmt.Printf()
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(paths)
```

Is there a better way or is this fine?

Comment: What problem did you have with `Walk`? Can you edit your post to include your Go code?

Comment: In your `info.IsDir()` case, you can use [ioutil.ReadDir(path)](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadDir) to get a list of `os.FileInfo` for each entry in that directory. Then you just need to check whether there are any directories in that list.

Answer (score 0):

this is a solution to find most deep directories of a given path.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

    // 1. Collect all directories
    var dirs []string
    filepath.Walk("..", func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if info.IsDir() {
            dirs = append(dirs, path)
        }
        return nil
    })

    // 2. Keep only those that do not match a (longer) subdirectory path
    var okDirs []string
    for _, maybe := range dirs {
        ok := true
        for _, d := range dirs {
            if len(d) > len(maybe) && strings.HasPrefix(d, maybe) {
                ok = false
                break
            }
        }
        if ok {
            okDirs = append(okDirs, maybe)
            fmt.Println(maybe)
        }
    }
    _ = okDirs
}
```